# Angular - Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I know this problem has been asked many time but I cannot find an answer.

I found a nice starting tutorial of just using controllers and services to run an api call and load some data onto the page.

I know however am looking to use routing to load different api data onto different pages.

Because of this, I know have:

```
//app.js

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'mainCtrl', 'randomCtrl', 'imageService']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    });
});
```

My controller:

```
//mainCtrl.js

angular.module('mainCtrl', [])

.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, Image) {
    // loading variable to show the spinning loading icon
    $scope.loading = true;

    Image.get()
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.images = data;
            $scope.loading = false;
            console.log(data);
        });

});
```

In the head of my file I have route linked:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script> <!-- load angular -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

My full error is this:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A29%3A115)
```

Everything worked fine when I was just using the controller to run the API call and then ng repeat the results. Using Laravel 5 if its any interest.

Comment: Angular makes me despair ...

Comment: `Image` doesn't appear to be part of the `mainCtrl` and is most likely the issue.

Comment: You know you don't have to make a module for each component, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the way your are trying to inject a service into your controller. You are doing it wrong. Also, I don't see why you should create a module for each controller / service.

Try to change you code to this and see if it works:

```
//app.js
// NO need to add other modules like your OWN controllers and services
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    });
});
```

Then, in your controller you inject the services that you need. You DONT have to add your OWN services and controller to `angular.module`. So your controller can look like this:

```
//mainCtrl.js

// Note that I'm using the "app" module instead of creating a new module
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', 'imageService', function($scope, $http, Image) {
    // loading variable to show the spinning loading icon
    $scope.loading = true;

    Image.get()
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.images = data;
            $scope.loading = false;
            console.log(data);
        });
}]);
```

I don't know how your `imageService` file looks like. But I guess this should do the trick.

A few things to note:

- Make sure you have included your `imageService.js` in your HTML
- Make sure the service is really called `imageService` (case sensitive!)

Comment: I receive app not defined errors with your controller. What seemed to fix the issue however is using a different link the scripts. I have now taken them from the angular site instead of a cdn / google and its working fine. When I get a chance ill use npm instead.